# What is the difference between pandas data frame and reading a csv files by lines?

Tags: pandas, csv

What is the difference between pandas data frame and reading csv files by lines?
How do I determine which method to use at the beginning of a project?

Comment: Pandas is large library designed to manipulate columns of data. Python's csv module is perfect for reading a CSV file row by row; you can manipulate columns with every iteration of a row. But, it really depends on your project.

Answer (score 0):

Pandas is very easy for manipulation of data. You can replace,fill,remove the null or specific value.pandas can handle   large dataset. Pandas provide many functions and method to apply.